# How to create a whatsapp like recording button with slide to cancel using Objective C in IPhone sdk

Tags: audio-recording, whatsapp

I want to create WhatsApp rolling out one-tap voice messaging feature in iPhone using objective c.

Comment: Hi, What have you finally used? I have the same requirement for my application.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is a very basic example. So whoever wants to use this, need a lot more to do. In case someone needs it in **Swift 3.x**

```html
import UIKit

protocol SPKRecordViewDelegate: class {
    
    func SPKRecordViewDidSelectRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView)
    func SPKRecordViewDidStopRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView)
    func SPKRecordViewDidCancelRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView)
    
}

class SPKRecordView: UIView {
    
    enum SPKRecordViewState {
        
        case Recording
        case None
        
    }
    
    var state : SPKRecordViewState = .None {
        
        didSet {
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { () -> Void in
                
                self.slideToCancel.alpha = 1.0
                self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
                self.setNeedsLayout()
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    let recordButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let slideToCancel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    
    weak var delegate : SPKRecordViewDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        setupRecordButton()
        setupLabel()
    }
    
    func setupRecordButton() {
        
        recordButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(recordButton)
        let hConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[recordButton]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["recordButton":recordButton])
        self.addConstraints(hConsts)
        
        let vConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[recordButton]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["recordButton":recordButton])
        self.addConstraints(vConsts)
        
        recordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "record")!, for: .normal)
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userDidTapRecord(_:)))
        longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        longPress.allowableMovement = 10
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
        recordButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
        
    }
    
    func setupLabel() {
        
        slideToCancel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(slideToCancel)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        let hConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[slideToCancel][bt]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["slideToCancel":slideToCancel,"bt":recordButton])
        self.addConstraints(hConsts)
        
        let vConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[slideToCancel]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["slideToCancel":slideToCancel])
        self.addConstraints(vConsts)
        
        slideToCancel.alpha = 0.0
        slideToCancel.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 17)
        slideToCancel.textAlignment = .center
        slideToCancel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    
    
    override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        if state == .none {
            return recordButton.intrinsicContentSize
        } else {
            
            return CGSize(width: recordButton.intrinsicContentSize.width * 3, height: recordButton.intrinsicContentSize.height)
        }
    }
    
    func userDidTapRecordThenSwipe(sender: UIButton) {
        slideToCancel.text = nil
        delegate?.SPKRecordViewDidCancelRecord(sender: self, button: sender)
    }
    
    func userDidStopRecording(sender: UIButton) {
        slideToCancel.text = nil
        delegate?.SPKRecordViewDidStopRecord(sender: self, button: sender)
    }
    
    func userDidBeginRecord(sender : UIButton) {
        slideToCancel.text = "Slide to cancel <"
        delegate?.SPKRecordViewDidSelectRecord(sender: self, button: sender)
        
    }
    
    func userDidTapRecord(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("Long Tap")
        
        let button = sender.view as! UIButton
        
        let location = sender.location(in: button)
        
        var startLocation = CGPoint.zero
        
        switch sender.state {
            
        case .began:
            startLocation = location
            userDidBeginRecord(sender: button)
        case .changed:
            
            let translate = CGPoint(x: location.x - startLocation.x, y: location.y - startLocation.y)
            
            if !button.bounds.contains(translate) {
                
                if state == .Recording {
                    userDidTapRecordThenSwipe(sender: button)
                }
            }
            
        case .ended:
            
            if state == .None { return }
            
            let translate = CGPoint(x: location.x - startLocation.x, y: location.y - startLocation.y)
            
            if !button.frame.contains(translate) {
                
                userDidStopRecording(sender: button)
                
            }
            
        case .failed, .possible ,.cancelled :
            
            if state == .Recording {
                userDidStopRecording(sender: button)
            }
            else {
                userDidTapRecordThenSwipe(sender: button)
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension ViewController : SPKRecordViewDelegate {
    
    func SPKRecordViewDidCancelRecord(sender: SPKRecordView, button: UIView) {
        
        sender.state = .None
        
        print("Cancelled")
    }
    
    func SPKRecordViewDidSelectRecord(sender: SPKRecordView, button: UIView) {
        
        sender.state = .Recording
        
        print("Began " + NSUUID().uuidString)
        
    }
    
    func SPKRecordViewDidStopRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView) {
        
        sender.state = .None
        
        print("Done")
    }
}
```

Usage :

```html
import UIKit

let rec = SPKRecordView(frame: CGRect.zero)

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        rec.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(rec)
        
        let hConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[bt]-(100)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["bt":rec])
        view.addConstraints(hConsts)
        
        let vConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(100)-[bt]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["bt":rec])
        view.addConstraints(vConsts)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something similar to Whatsapp recording behavior just for fun but it is written in `Swift 2.1`

```
protocol SPKRecordViewDelegate: class {

func SPKRecordViewDidSelectRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView)
func SPKRecordViewDidStopRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView)
func SPKRecordViewDidCancelRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView)

}

class SPKRecordView: UIView {

enum SPKRecordViewState {

    case Recording
    case None

}

var state : SPKRecordViewState = .None {

    didSet {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in

            self.slideToCancel.alpha = 1.0
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()

        }

    }
}

let recordButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
let slideToCancel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)

weak var delegate : SPKRecordViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    setupRecordButton()
    setupLabel()
}

func setupRecordButton() {

    recordButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(recordButton)
    let hConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[recordButton]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["recordButton":recordButton])
    self.addConstraints(hConsts)

    let vConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[recordButton]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["recordButton":recordButton])
    self.addConstraints(vConsts)

    recordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "record")!, forState: .Normal)
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "userDidTapRecord:")
    longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    longPress.allowableMovement = 10
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
    recordButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

}

func setupLabel() {

    slideToCancel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(slideToCancel)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let hConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[slideToCancel][bt]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["slideToCancel":slideToCancel,"bt":recordButton])
    self.addConstraints(hConsts)

    let vConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[slideToCancel]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["slideToCancel":slideToCancel])
    self.addConstraints(vConsts)

    slideToCancel.alpha = 0.0
    slideToCancel.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 17)
    slideToCancel.textAlignment = .Center
    slideToCancel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {

    if state == .None {
        return recordButton.intrinsicContentSize()
    } else {

        return CGSizeMake(recordButton.intrinsicContentSize().width * 3, recordButton.intrinsicContentSize().height)
    }
}

func userDidTapRecordThenSwipe(sender: UIButton) {
    slideToCancel.text = nil
    delegate?.SPKRecordViewDidCancelRecord(self, button: sender)
}

func userDidStopRecording(sender: UIButton) {
    slideToCancel.text = nil
    delegate?.SPKRecordViewDidStopRecord(self, button: sender)
}

func userDidBeginRecord(sender : UIButton) {
    slideToCancel.text = "Slide to cancel <"
    delegate?.SPKRecordViewDidSelectRecord(self, button: sender)

}

func userDidTapRecord(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let button = gesture.view as! UIButton

    let location = gesture.locationInView(button)

    var startLocation = CGPointZero

    switch gesture.state {

    case .Began:
            startLocation = location
            userDidBeginRecord(button)
    case .Changed:

        let translate = CGPoint(x: location.x - startLocation.x, y: location.y - startLocation.y)

        if !CGRectContainsPoint(button.bounds, translate) {

            if state == .Recording {
                userDidTapRecordThenSwipe(button)
            }
        }

    case .Ended:

        if state == .None { return }

        let translate = CGPoint(x: location.x - startLocation.x, y: location.y - startLocation.y)

        if !CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, translate) {

            userDidStopRecording(button)

        }

    case .Failed, .Possible ,.Cancelled : if state == .Recording { userDidStopRecording(button) } else { userDidTapRecordThenSwipe(button)}
    }


}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

extension ViewController : SPKRecordViewDelegate {

func SPKRecordViewDidCancelRecord(sender: SPKRecordView, button: UIView) {

    sender.state = .None

    print("Cancelled")
}

func SPKRecordViewDidSelectRecord(sender: SPKRecordView, button: UIView) {

    sender.state = .Recording

    print("Began " + NSUUID().UUIDString)

}

func SPKRecordViewDidStopRecord(sender : SPKRecordView, button: UIView) {

    sender.state = .None

    print("Done")
}
}
```

Usage :

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {


let rec = SPKRecordView(frame: CGRectZero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    rec.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(rec)

    let hConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[bt]-(100)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["bt":rec])
    view.addConstraints(hConsts)

    let vConsts = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(100)-[bt]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["bt":rec])
    view.addConstraints(vConsts)
}
}
```

Comment: Please give me this swift file . Bcz i am trying to make this file but getting lot's of errors.Thanks

Comment: if you have visible demo it's reduce my 2 days work.So if possible give me demo code link. Thanks